# Using a sniffed packet with scapy python

Tags: python, packet, packet-sniffers, sniffing, sniffer

Im not so new to network programming but new to working with scapy (I mainly work on c++).

So, im sniffing packets (traffic) that are coming into my computer and what I want to do is just to save one of the packets into a variable and use it later in my program.
It doesnt need to be any specific packet it can be a random packet. The only thing I want is just to insert it into a variable and use it later on.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: yes, I tried to save it to a pcap file but with no prevail.

Comment: All I can think of is to when im printing the packet info just to save it into a list maybe if I want to use some packets or just to save it into a temp variable....
Worth a try

Answer (score 0):

The sniff() function returns the sniffed packet. You can pass various arguments to this function. You can take the output and save it in a variable. Please see these two links:
(a) www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf and (b)
and [Scapy filtering with sniff() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210879/scapy-filtering-with-sniff-function)